# Find which process is using a file

Tags: windows, io, filesystems, process

I'm trying to access a file from the application I'm developing, but I get an error that states the file is already opened by another program.

Ok, I launched first handle, then process explorer, then process monitor which all said the same thing:

```
Handle v3.45
Copyright (C) 1997-2011 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

No matching handles found.
```

What else can I do (for now a reboot seems the only solution) to find the process using my files?

Answer (score 3):

LockHunter (http://lockhunter.com) can help you with this.

It has been reviewed here http://dottech.org/10534/unlocker-vs-lockhunter-which-one-should-you-get-for-your-file-unlocking-needs/ You can google for more reviews if you want to be double sure. I've used it and it was helpful.

Comment: Occasionally, Process Explorer doesn't work, and I've just tried LockHunter and it does seem to work (though I'd still go with Process Explorer as the go-to program to check for what's locking a file/folder).

Answer (score 1):

A handy trick on Windows 7 (not sure about other versions) is to try and delete the file (or modify it), when it tells you it can't delete it because it's in use it sometimes tells you the program that is using it.

If still no joy then I think your right, just reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately not the case here…